# Insomnia: how do I reference a windows environment variable in Insomnia?

Tags: insomnia

I want to use a windows environment variable in Insomnia. There is an option to read OS properties, which I thought would allow me to use windows env variables but it's not obvious how. In the below I am trying to add "testWE" and I am trying using OS/userInfo.

[image]

Another option is to use a custom function but again I am not familiar with this syntax

[image]

Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [insomnia-plugin-system-env](https://insomnia.rest/plugins/insomnia-plugin-system-env) plugin.

Example:

[image: screenshot of insomnia using insomnia-plugin-system-env]