# Why are the environment variables not updating when using insomnia-plugin-system-env?

Tags: insomnia

I am using insomnia-plugin-system-env after following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75371183/8229265)

Although I can get the environment variable value, it is not changing in Insomnia's live preview. i.e. it does not update, once it gets the value for the system variable.

Even after I click the refresh button and set it to environment variable instead of static.

The prompts that goes to obtain these commands are these two:
`{% system_env 'env_var' %}` and `{{env_var}}`

What can I do so that it should update the variables' value, each time it is read/accessed?
Also, is there any other way to do this?